# resolving constructor dependency at runtime (without attributes)

Tags: c#, unity-container

I am using Unity for dependency injection and I want to control at runtime, which particular type is resolved and passed into a constructor as a dependency.

I have an interface:

```
public interface IDatabase
{
    void DoSomething();
}
```

That is implemented by two classes:

```
public class SQLDatabase : IDatabase
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        //Do Something on a SQL server database...
    }
}
public class OracleDatabase : IDatabase
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        //Do Something on an Oracle database...
    }
}
```

A third class has a dependency on IDatabase

```
public class DataService: IDataService
{
    public DataService(IDatabase database)
    {
        database.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

The module registers each class with Unity and the two IDatabase types are given specific names so that they can be differentiated:

```
container.RegisterType<IDatabase, SQLDatabase>("SQLDatabase");
container.RegisterType<IDatabase, OracleDatabase>("OracleDatabase");
container.RegisterType<IDataService, DataService>();
```

I need to create an instance of a Consumer, at which point I want to specify which of the two types that implement IDatabase are to be used/injected by Unity, but I don't know how to tell Unity which specific type to construct/resolve?  I guess I want something like this (Pseudo code):

```
public class Consumer
{
    IDataService dataService = null;
    public Consumer(string runtimeChoice)
    {
        if (runtimeChoice == "SQLSERVER")
        {
            dataService = _container.Resolve<IDataService>("SQLDatabase");
        }
        else if (runtimeChoice == "Oracle")
        {
            dataService = _container.Resolve<IDataService>("OracleDatabase");
        }
    }
}
```

So, how do I tell Unity to resolve the IDatabase type, using the specific named type, and pass it into the constructor of dependent objects, but doing it at runtime?

Comment: Make it a parameter of the method that returns a configured container probably.

Comment: To you really want to switch database while the application is running or is this `runtimeChoice` a value that fixed after startup (i.e. placed in the application's configuration file)?

Comment: Nope it won't be changed while running, however it needs to be selected at runtime. The user has multiple sources available, so the code needs to cope with a selection at runtime.

Answer (score 4):

There are two things I would change, I would try to ensure those magic strings were handled as close to their source as possible and I would try to ensure my code was container agnostic.

I would have the following interface:

```
public interface IDataServiceFactory
{
    IDataService CreateSqlDataService();
    IDataService CreateOracleDataService();
}
```

With an implementation like so:

```
public class DataServiceFactory : IDataServiceFactory
{
    private readonly Func<IDataService> _sqlDataServiceFactory;
    private readonly Func<IDataService> _oracleDataServiceFactory;

    public DataServiceFactory(Func<IDataService> sqlDataServiceFactory, Func<IDataService> oracleDataServiceFactory)
    {
        _sqlDataServiceFactory = sqlDataServiceFactory;
        _oracleDataServiceFactory = oracleDataServiceFactory;
    }

    public IDataService CreateSqlDataService()
    {
        return _sqlDataServiceFactory();
    }


    public IDataService CreateOracleDataService()
    {
        return _oracleDataServiceFactory();
    }
}
```

I would then register this with your `IUnityContainer` like so:

```
_container.RegisterType<IDataService, DataService>("SQLDataService", 
    new InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedParameter<IDatabase>("SQLDatabase")));

_container.RegisterType<IDataService, DataService>("OracleDataService", 
    new InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedParameter<IDatabase>("OracleDatabase")));

_container.RegisterType<IDataServiceFactory, DataServiceFactory>(new InjectionConstructor(
    new ResolvedParameter<Func<IDataService>>("SQLDataService"), 
    new ResolvedParameter<Func<IDataService>>("OracleDataService"));
```

Now whatever was previously creating your `Consumer` instances should now have a dependency on `IDataServiceFactory` and should handle the runtime value to call the correct method `CreateSqlDataService()` or `CreateOracleDataService()`.

All of your runtime code is now container agnostic and the magic strings are handled right next to their source.

Comment: Thanks. In this case there were no actual magic strings, I was just trying to demonstrate the situation that the user is making a selection at runtime, and that affects which object needed to be resolved as a dependency.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to resolve the correct type using a DependencyOverride, which itself obtained the required type from the unity container. So the consumer becomes:

```
public class Consumer
{
    IDataService dataService = null;
    public Consumer(string runtimeChoice)
    {
        DependencyOverride<IDatabase> dependency = null;

        if (runtimeChoice == "SQLSERVER")
        {
            dependency = new DependencyOverride<IDatabase>
                                 (Container.Resolve<IDatabase>("SQLDatabase"));

        }
        else if (runtimeChoice == "Oracle")
        {
            dependency = new DependencyOverride<IDatabase>
                                 (Container.Resolve<IDatabase>("OracleDatabase"));
        }            

        dataService = _container.Resolve<IDataService>(dependency);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar requirement where I need to resolve a 'widgetbuilder' type at runtime. In my Unity Configuration I register my two types of widget builders:-

```
        container.RegisterType<IWidgetBuilder, SinglePointWidgetBuilder>("SinglePointWidgetBuilder");
        container.RegisterType<IWidgetBuilder, CurrentVsTargetWidgetBuilder>("CurrentVsTargetWidgetBuilder");
```

I then resolve them at runtime by:-

```
var container = UnityConfig.GetConfiguredContainer();
var widgetBuilder = container.Resolve<IWidgetBuilder>("SinglePointWidgetBuilder");
```